# UISegmentedControl titletext is blurry

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uisegmentedcontrol

I have implemented a header view in a collection view.
It is a UISegmentedControll with three items.

Here is the code:

```
NSArray *itemArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"Following", @"Everybody", @"Nearby", nil];
UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:itemArray];
UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"PatuaOne-Regular" size:12.0f];

UIColor *notChosenButtonColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(201.0/255.0f) green:(198.0/255.0f) blue:(191.0/255.0f) alpha:1.0];
UIColor *chosenButtonColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(235.0/255.0f) green:(218.0/255.0f) blue:(102.0/255.0f) alpha:1.0];

NSDictionary *normalAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            font, UITextAttributeFont,
                            notChosenButtonColor, UITextAttributeTextColor,
                            nil];
NSDictionary *selectedAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                  font, UITextAttributeFont,
                                  chosenButtonColor, UITextAttributeTextColor,
                                  nil];
[segmentedControl setTitleTextAttributes:normalAttributes forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[segmentedControl setTitleTextAttributes:selectedAttributes forState:UIControlStateSelected];

[segmentedControl setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"greenbt_bg.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[segmentedControl setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"standard_bt_h"] forState:UIControlStateSelected barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[segmentedControl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor] ];

segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(5, 20, 280, 25);
segmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStylePlain;
segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;

[segmentedControl setDividerImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"separator.png"]
            forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal
              rightSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal
                     barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

[headerView addSubview:segmentedControl];
```

The segmentedcontrol now looks like this:

[image: UISegmentedControl]

Why is the text of the segments blurry when not selected?

**Edit**

Solved it! added `[UIColor clearColor], UITextAttributeTextShadowColor` to `normalAttributes`

Comment: probably because of shadow color. Looks like a gray color with a white shadow. Try to set `UITextAttributeTextShadowColor` and `UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset` to your needs. For a quick test you can use [UIColor clearColor] as shadowColor. You'll see if it's caused by the shadow.

Comment: Wow thanks! that solved it! :) Post your answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is most likely caused by the default shadowColor.

Try to set `UITextAttributeTextShadowColor` and `UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset` in your titleTextAttributes.

You might have to experiment to get the best visual appearance. You can also simply set the shadowColor attribute to `[UIColor clearColor]`.

Comment: Thanks! this is a great solution. I was facing the same problem

Answer (score 0):

It's also possible that you are setting a frame that is between pixel boundaries. Using `CGRectIntegral` did the trick for me.